# Relay working below rated coil Voltage

Tags: relay

Hey guys I am using leone sc5 ag 12v DC relay I want to know what happens if we apply 8v,10v or any other less than 12v dc,will it turn on or it will remain off?

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: What does the datasheet give for 'pull in' voltage?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can find this information in the datasheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a garden-variety single-side-stable relay there are two voltages noted on the data sheet, the "must make" or "pull-in" coil voltage, at which the relay is guaranteed to energize, and the "must break" or "dropout" coil voltage, at which the relay is guaranteed to de-energize.

The relay's behavior is hysteretic, however, which means that if its contacts are in their stable state, (coil de-energized) they're **guaranteed** to switch into the unstable state when the coil voltage rises to the coil's pull-in voltage, but they **could** switch into the unstable state at any coil voltage between the pull-in and drop-out values.

Conversely, when the relay is in its unstable state, (coil energized) it's **guaranteed** to revert to its stable state when the coil voltage falls to the drop-out voltage, but it **could** revert to the unstable state at any coil voltage between the pull-in and drop-out values, as illustrated below.

[image]

Then there's also the question of what happens when the coil heats up because of its \$ I^2 R \$ losses or because of changes in its ambient temperature.

For the SC5 relay with a 12 volt coil, the coil's resistance is about 400 ohms (ostensibly at 25C) and, with a guaranteed pull-in of 9 volts, will have a coil current of 22.5 milliamperes. This is the minimum current guaranteed to energize the relay and, since copper has a positive temperature coefficient of resistance, as the coil heats up its resistance will increase, requiring the voltage across it to increase in order to maintain the 22.5 mA coil current.

Copper exhibits a thermal coefficient of resistance (A) of 0.00427 ohms per ohm  per degree C, and to find the coil's resistance at its upper temperature limit of 70C we can use the simplified Callendar-Van Dusen formula:

$$ Rt = R20(1+A (T2 - T1))= 400\Omega \times( 1 + (A \times (70C -20C)))\approx \text{ 486 ohms} $$

Since the magnetic field surrounding the coil (and keeping the relay energized)  must be generated by at least 22.5 mA of coil current, the coil's increase in resistance to 486 ohms will require the pull-in voltage to increase to:

$$ E = IR = 0.0225A \times 486\Omega \approx \text { 11 volts}  $$

So, with a 12 volt supply and the coil at 70C, the relay will still work, **plus** it'll have one volt of headroom.

Hmm... sounds like the relay guys know what they're doing. :)

Comment: +1 Perhaps worth mentioning that make and break voltages are heavily temperature dependent. Pull in voltage at maximum coil temperature can be 20-30% higher than at room temperature.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: Thanks, Spehro, excellent suggestion. :)

Answer (score 2):

Below the drop-out voltage, the relay will always be off.

Above the pull-in voltage, the relay will always be on.

Between those two voltages, the relay won't change state. There is a form of hysteresis due to the magnetic circuit closing when the relay goes on.

Usually the pull-in voltage will be 60% to 80% ish of the rated voltage, the data sheet will tell you exactly what is guaranteed.

The drop-out voltage will be somewhat less than the pull-in voltage. The data sheet will tell you exactly what it is. For some relays, the drop-out voltage is a surprisingly small fraction of the rated voltage.

Comment: PDF]www.leonerelays.com

, here it is datasheet and relay is in PCB 12 v sc5 ag

Comment: Excellent, so you have the data sheet. Go to the 12v relay section, and look up pull-in and drop-out voltages as a proportion of rated voltage.

Comment: While the pull-in voltage is **guaranteed** to be  9v, there's nothing prohibiting it from being, say 8V.  In the same vein, while the drop-out voltage is **guaranteed** to be 1.2V, there's nothing prohibiting it from being, say, 2.2V.